# How to perform a series of image processing steps at runtime in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, graphicsmagick

I am using the gm Node module for cropping and making thumbnails of images.
Here's what I'm trying to do...

```
var img = gm("./myImage.jpg");
var thmb;

if(options.crop)
   img = img.crop(100, 50, 10, 10);

if(options.resize)
   thmb = img.resize(240);

img.stream(callback);

if(thmb)
   thmb.stream(callback2);
```

**Expected result:**

The above code should output two images ('img' and 'thmb'). 'img' should be cropped version of the original image and 'thmb' should be the cropped AND resized version of original.

**Actual result**

'img' output is cropped as expected but the 'thmb' is ONLY a resized version of the original image. It's not cropped as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `gm` works you have to use one chain of transformations per desired output, even if the input is the same. So if you want to do A and B on a file `foo.jpg`, and put the output in one file, and do only B on the same input file but put the output in a *different file*, you'd have to do:

```
var gm = require("gm");
gm("./foo.jpg").A().B().stream(...);
gm("./foo.jpg").B().stream(...);
```

The operations on the objects returned by `gm` return the same object they ware called on. So `img.crop(...) === img` is true. The example uses `crop` but this is generally true for other operations too. So if you do `thmb = img.resize(...)` then after this operation `thmb === img` is true. This is why you have to create two *separate* objects with `gm(...)`.

So somethig like this should do what you want:

```
var gm = require("gm");
var fs = require("fs");

options = {
    resize: true,
    crop: true
};

var img = gm("./myImage.jpg");
var thmb = options.resize ? gm("./myImage.jpg") : undefined;

if(options.crop)
   img = img.crop(500, 50, 10, 10);
   if (thmb)
       thmb = thmb.crop(500, 50, 10, 10);

if(options.resize)
    thmb = thmb.resize(240);

img.stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./out.jpg"));
});


if(thmb)
   thmb.stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
       stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./thumb.jpg"));
   });
```

I've changed the crop parameters to give a width of 500 because resizing to a width of 240 after cropping to a width of 100 does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Louis. I realized that I had made a mistake in my code snippet. I have updated my question now. Sorry for the bother.

Comment: Thanks again Louis! That's what I suspected too. I was trying to avoid running the crop operation twice but I guess that's not possible.

Comment: It might not be as bad as you think. What `gm` does is just accumulating a bunch of options which eventually it passes to an external `graphicsmagick` or `imagemagick` process. Run your code with the environment variable `DEBUG=*` and `gm` will output the commands it spawns. If one of your operations were a really long computation, then it would be worth creating an intermediary file, and producing the two final files from this intermediary so as to avoid repeating the costly operation. But for `crop` and `resize` there's no point in trying to optimize it.